# Magento 1.3 Custom layout cache issue

Tags: xml, caching, layout, magento

I have a custom module to display a very simple page on my magento site. Its using its own layout file which is specified in the config.xml file.

When the cache is turned off and all the cache files are manually deleted, the page renders just fine. Once the cache is turned on, or refreshed once on the page doesn't pickup the layout file anymore so a blank page with default layout is displayed.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: There's not enough information here to help. Describe how you've added your own layout file, and describe the block it adds.

Comment: how do you specify custom layout in your module's config file?

Answer (score 1):

I found that it was the use_cache.ser file that was still holding some of the details I needed to clear. So now whenever I need to be sure to clear all cache files I delete the following:
var/cache/*
var/session/*
app/etc/use_cache.ser

Answer (score -1):

You can clear the cache manually from

```
/path to your magento installation/var/cache
```

Just delete everything under cache directory.

Comment: var/cache/*
var/session/*
app/etc/use_cache.ser